# Using dplyr to normalize against a group control

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

My dataset contains three factors: "line", "dop" and "conc". Each "line" group has four rows on which "dop" and "conc" values are "control". Below you can find a working example of the dataset:

```
line;dop;conc;prol
a;undop;100;0,1540
a;undop;100;0,2770
a;undop;100;0,2460
a;0,0175;100;0,2030
a;0,0175;100;0,1630
a;0,0175;100;0,2300
a;0,015;100;0,2960
a;0,015;100;0,1070
a;0,015;100;0,2450
a;0,013;100;0,1890
a;0,013;100;0,2910
a;0,013;100;0,2490
a;0,02;100;0,1250
a;0,02;100;0,2910
a;0,02;100;0,2650
a;0,01;100;0,2040
a;0,01;100;0,1030
a;0,01;100;0,1100
a;0,005;100;0,1770
a;0,005;100;0,2890
a;0,005;100;0,1920
a;0,001;100;0,2820
a;0,001;100;0,2480
a;0,001;100;0,1320
a;control;control;0,1640
a;undop;10;0,2920
a;undop;10;0,2580
a;undop;10;0,1900
a;0,0175;10;0,2060
a;0,0175;10;0,2860
a;0,0175;10;0,1010
a;0,015;10;0,2720
a;0,015;10;0,1300
a;0,015;10;0,2720
a;0,013;10;0,2760
a;0,013;10;0,2910
a;0,013;10;0,2630
a;0,02;10;0,1900
a;0,02;10;0,2710
a;0,02;10;0,1770
a;0,01;10;0,2980
a;0,01;10;0,2580
a;0,01;10;0,1500
a;0,005;10;0,3000
a;0,005;10;0,2510
a;0,005;10;0,1990
a;0,001;10;0,1270
a;0,001;10;0,2040
a;0,001;10;0,2860
a;control;control;0,1300
a;undop;1;0,2780
a;undop;1;0,1250
a;undop;1;0,2710
a;0,0175;1;0,1000
a;0,0175;1;0,2920
a;0,0175;1;0,2340
a;0,015;1;0,1620
a;0,015;1;0,1230
a;0,015;1;0,2770
a;0,013;1;0,1330
a;0,013;1;0,1880
a;0,013;1;0,2530
a;0,02;1;0,1410
a;0,02;1;0,1720
a;0,02;1;0,1780
a;0,01;1;0,2190
a;0,01;1;0,1650
a;0,01;1;0,1260
a;0,005;1;0,1210
a;0,005;1;0,1200
a;0,005;1;0,1160
a;0,001;1;0,1720
a;0,001;1;0,1320
a;0,001;1;0,2410
a;control;control;0,2590
a;undop;0,1;0,1880
a;undop;0,1;0,2340
a;undop;0,1;0,1950
a;0,0175;0,1;0,1630
a;0,0175;0,1;0,1190
a;0,0175;0,1;0,2250
a;0,015;0,1;0,2520
a;0,015;0,1;0,2890
a;0,015;0,1;0,2150
a;0,013;0,1;0,2850
a;0,013;0,1;0,1350
a;0,013;0,1;0,2550
a;0,02;0,1;0,2810
a;0,02;0,1;0,1810
a;0,02;0,1;0,2000
a;0,01;0,1;0,1320
a;0,01;0,1;0,2730
a;0,01;0,1;0,2570
a;0,005;0,1;0,1740
a;0,005;0,1;0,1830
a;0,005;0,1;0,2910
a;0,001;0,1;0,2580
a;0,001;0,1;0,1500
a;0,001;0,1;0,1480
a;control;control;0,2870
b;undop;100;0,2530
b;undop;100;0,1860
b;undop;100;0,1820
b;0,0175;100;0,2850
b;0,0175;100;0,1620
b;0,0175;100;0,2130
b;0,015;100;0,2900
b;0,015;100;0,2610
b;0,015;100;0,1900
b;0,013;100;0,1030
b;0,013;100;0,2650
b;0,013;100;0,2640
b;0,02;100;0,1580
b;0,02;100;0,2470
b;0,02;100;0,2730
b;0,01;100;0,2280
b;0,01;100;0,1850
b;0,01;100;0,2340
b;0,005;100;0,1170
b;0,005;100;0,2370
b;0,005;100;0,1160
b;0,001;100;0,2830
b;0,001;100;0,1560
b;0,001;100;0,1330
b;control;control;0,1410
b;undop;10;0,3000
b;undop;10;0,1430
b;undop;10;0,2910
b;0,0175;10;0,2350
b;0,0175;10;0,2500
b;0,0175;10;0,2100
b;0,015;10;0,1210
b;0,015;10;0,2220
b;0,015;10;0,1360
b;0,013;10;0,2070
b;0,013;10;0,2650
b;0,013;10;0,1450
b;0,02;10;0,2090
b;0,02;10;0,1060
b;0,02;10;0,2520
b;0,01;10;0,1700
b;0,01;10;0,2550
b;0,01;10;0,1570
b;0,005;10;0,1430
b;0,005;10;0,1060
b;0,005;10;0,1740
b;0,001;10;0,1980
b;0,001;10;0,1090
b;0,001;10;0,2330
b;control;control;0,2650
b;undop;1;0,2320
b;undop;1;0,2470
b;undop;1;0,2070
b;0,0175;1;0,2610
b;0,0175;1;0,2090
b;0,0175;1;0,1250
b;0,015;1;0,2780
b;0,015;1;0,2190
b;0,015;1;0,2720
b;0,013;1;0,1500
b;0,013;1;0,2400
b;0,013;1;0,2000
b;0,02;1;0,1780
b;0,02;1;0,1320
b;0,02;1;0,1680
b;0,01;1;0,1430
b;0,01;1;0,1660
b;0,01;1;0,2370
b;0,005;1;0,2040
b;0,005;1;0,2870
b;0,005;1;0,2710
b;0,001;1;0,1460
b;0,001;1;0,1150
b;0,001;1;0,2070
b;control;control;0,2200
b;undop;0,1;0,2680
b;undop;0,1;0,2620
b;undop;0,1;0,2510
b;0,0175;0,1;0,2100
b;0,0175;0,1;0,2980
b;0,0175;0,1;0,1740
b;0,015;0,1;0,2320
b;0,015;0,1;0,1230
b;0,015;0,1;0,2800
b;0,013;0,1;0,1830
b;0,013;0,1;0,1940
b;0,013;0,1;0,2580
b;0,02;0,1;0,2120
b;0,02;0,1;0,2820
b;0,02;0,1;0,1780
b;0,01;0,1;0,2470
b;0,01;0,1;0,2500
b;0,01;0,1;0,2760
b;0,005;0,1;0,1780
b;0,005;0,1;0,1880
b;0,005;0,1;0,1350
b;0,001;0,1;0,1260
b;0,001;0,1;0,2580
b;0,001;0,1;0,2840
b;control;control;0,1880
```

What I want, is to normalize each value of prol variable **of every "dop" and "conc" row** against the mean of the four control values I mentioned before.

Basically, you should divide every "prol" value of line a by the mean of the prol values of its controls and multiply it by 100. i.e.:
The mean of the controls belonging to line A is:

```
  line  dop     conc     prol
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <dbl>
1 a     control control 0.164
2 a     control control 0.13 
3 a     control control 0.259
4 a     control control 0.287
```

> (0,1640+0,1300+0,2590+0,2870)/4 = 0.21

Now every prol value of line A should be divided by this number and multiplied by 100:

```
   line  dop    conc   prol
   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
 1 a     undop  100   0.154
 2 a     undop  100   0.277
```

> 0.1540/0.21x100=73.33

> 0.2770/0.21x100=131.9

> and so on.

The same should be done to line B.

With the following lines I've managed to do it, but it only normalizes the data corresponding to the controls, and skips all the useful data corresponding to the rest of the "dopaje" and "concentracion" levels:

```
dummy %>%
  group_by(line) %>%
  filter(dop=="control") %>%
  mutate(ctrl=prol/mean(prol)*100)

# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   line [2]
  line  dop     conc     prol  ctrl
  <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     control control 0.164  78.1
2 a     control control 0.13   61.9
3 a     control control 0.259 123. 
4 a     control control 0.287 137. 
5 b     control control 0.141  69.3
6 b     control control 0.265 130. 
7 b     control control 0.22  108. 
8 b     control control 0.188  92.4
```

You can see that ctrl column now shows the successfully calculated values, but it only does for the control values, skipping all the useful rest of the data.

How can I expand that mutation to all the rows and not only the "control" ones? I've tried using "cur_data()" which seems a new feature in dplyr, but haven't managed to make it work.

Thanks a lot in advance!

JP.

Comment: The second data set that you have applied a filter on `control` seems ok, how would you like the output to be?

Comment: I want the output shown in the second dataset, except that the output I'm showing is made with excel. I want to have that output but made with R.

Comment: I usually handle this by creating a data frame containing the values I would like to use for normalization using `filter`, `group_by`, and `summarize`, and `left_join` this back to the original data frame. Then you can use mutate to calculate prol_norm. If you could post some of your data, we could be more helpful. Copy output of `(dput(df))` into your question.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I have already a reprex of my data at the beginning of the post. You should be able to work with that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and neatest way to solve this, as showed in [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-normalize-data-against-control-group/100902/2) is this:

```
dummy %>%
    group_by(line) %>%
    mutate(ctrl=prol/mean(prol[dop=="control"])*100)

# A tibble: 200 x 5
# Groups:   line [2]
   line  dop    conc   prol  ctrl
   <chr> <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a     undop  100   0.154  73.3
 2 a     undop  100   0.277 132. 
 3 a     undop  100   0.246 117. 
 4 a     0,0175 100   0.203  96.7
 5 a     0,0175 100   0.163  77.6
 6 a     0,0175 100   0.23  110. 
 7 a     0,015  100   0.296 141. 
 8 a     0,015  100   0.107  51.0
 9 a     0,015  100   0.245 117. 
10 a     0,013  100   0.189  90  
# ... with 190 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this works for your data set. For this purpose I first computed the grouped mean and then divide every `prol` by it rowwise:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(linea) %>%
  mutate(avg_prol = mean(prol)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(ctrl = (prol / avg_prol) * 100) %>%
  select(-avg_prol)

# A tibble: 16 x 6
# Rowwise:  linea
   linea        dopaje  concentracion  prol prol_norm  ctrl
   <chr>        <chr>   <chr>         <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 fibroblastos control control       0.26       98.7  98.7
 2 fibroblastos control control       0.262      99.4  99.4
 3 fibroblastos control control       0.284     108   108. 
 4 fibroblastos control control       0.248      94.1  94.1
 5 a375         control control       0.851     100   100. 
 6 a375         control control       0.821      96.8  96.8
 7 a375         control control       0.912     108   108. 
 8 a375         control control       0.809      95.4  95.4
 9 hela         control control       0.457     107   107. 
10 hela         control control       0.38       88.6  88.6
11 hela         control control       0.432     101   101. 
12 hela         control control       0.447     104   104. 
13 mcf7         control control       0.294     100   100. 
14 mcf7         control control       0.258      88.2  88.1
15 mcf7         control control       0.286      97.7  97.6
16 mcf7         control control       0.334     114   114.
```

Data:

```
df <- tribble(
  ~linea,        ~dopaje,  ~concentracion,  ~prol, ~prol_norm,
 "fibroblastos", "control", "control",       0.260,      98.7,
 "fibroblastos", "control", "control",       0.262,      99.4,
 "fibroblastos", "control", "control",       0.284,     108., 
 "fibroblastos", "control", "control",       0.248,      94.1,
 "a375",         "control", "control",       0.851,     100., 
 "a375",         "control", "control",       0.821,      96.8,
 "a375",         "control", "control",       0.912,     108., 
 "a375",         "control", "control",       0.809,      95.4,
 "hela",         "control", "control",       0.457,     107., 
 "hela",         "control", "control",       0.38,       88.6,
 "hela",         "control", "control",       0.432,     101., 
 "hela",         "control", "control",       0.447,     104., 
 "mcf7",         "control", "control",       0.294,     100., 
 "mcf7",         "control", "control",       0.258,     88.2,
 "mcf7",         "control", "control",       0.286,      97.7,
 "mcf7",         "control", "control",       0.334,     114.
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is what I already achieved. Mutating only the previously filtered rows. I want to apply the mutation to all the rows belonging to the linea group (no only the control group).

Comment: I'm a bit confused here but maybe if you share an unfiltered excerpt of your data, we can help you better.

Comment: Hi again and thanks a lot for your patience. I've updated the post, so hopefully you can understand it better now. You have a random excerpt of my dataset already (it's the second one). Thanks again!

Comment: It's ok, I only need a reproducible piece of your raw data. Could you share that?

Comment: The other problem is your dopaje and concentracion columns are a mixture of character and numeric vector which will automatically coerced into character vector.

Comment: I have updated the post again giving you a dataset. Please be aware decimal points are indicated with commas. I hope it is useful, thanks a lot again.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't think I have a solution for this as the some columns are a combinations of character and numeric values and I don't now to deal with them.

Comment: You can treat them all as characters, they're all factors, they're irrelevant for the purpose of normalization. Thanks a lot anyway! :)